# how to return list of result from sequelizejs to grpc?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, grpc

How can I return a list of users using grpc, the result is empty:

I am http://condorjs.com, to create the grpc server

```
class User {
  getUser(ctx) {
    models.users.findAll({
            where: { userId: ctx.req.userId }
        }).then(function(users){
            // return a list of users
           for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
             result.push({'userId': users[i].userId, 'userName': users[i].userName);
           }

           return { 'users': result};
        });
     }
   }

const options = {
      'listen': '0.0.0.0:50051',
      'rootProtoPath': 'protos',
   };

   const app = new Condor(options)
    .add('user.proto', 'User', new User())
    .start();
```

GRPC client call:

```
var PROTO_PATH = __dirname + '/../proto/profile.proto';

var grpc = require('grpc');
var user_proto = grpc.load(PROTO_PATH).user;

function main() {
  var client = new guser_proto.User('localhost:50051',
                                       grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

    client.getUser({userId: '8888'}, function(err, response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
}

main();
```

The proto:

```
message UserResponse {
    message User{
        string userId = 1;
        string userName = 2;
    }

    repeated User users= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent received any callback method at function definition so i added a callback parameter, this callback method will be called with required parameters. You will receive data at your main method

```
 getUser(ctx, callback) {
    models.users.findAll({
            where: { userId: ctx.req.userId }
        }).then(function(users){
            // return a list of users
           for (var i = 0, len = users.length; i < len; i++) {
             result.push({'userId': users[i].userId, 'userName': users[i].userName);
           }

           callback(null,{ 'users': result});
        }.bind(this));
     }
   }
```

This will surely return your data at here

```
function main() {
  var client = new guser_proto.User('localhost:50051',
                                       grpc.credentials.createInsecure());

    client.getUser({userId: '8888'}, function(err, response) {
      console.log(response); // it will print here 
    });
}
```

Comment: how are you receiving the values ? and secondly, does this "users" object have any data? Can you print it and check

Comment: yes console.log give me the result : [ { userId: 'c46c4c9a0968450498f8de748d630c75' },
  { userId: '528ee92bbe9f4d3cbrc66fccf85cfb4c' },
  { userId: '3cd8004252454ae290e056999dec4ef7' } ]

Comment: So its working, right? Only problem is you are not treating data very well. This method will be called asynchronously, so you need to add a callback method or some other way to get the value in calling method. I can help you if you show me the usage of this code

Comment: Yes, I think is the async problem, if I just return the array, it work. Updated my question.

Comment: I am using condor framework to create the grpc server.

Comment: @Alvin where are you calling "getUser" method? i dont see it in your code?

Comment: I got callback is not a function

Comment: @Alvin can you please log callback? i want to know what's the value of it?

Comment: @Alvin, it could be because of context. also i updated call of callback method. Please try this.

Comment: callback is undefined

Comment: I got it, i have updated my answer, can you please try with this. I updated these 2 lines ->  callback(null,{ 'users': result});
        }.bind(this));